# Fooling a DOS in game timer

Tags: ms-dos, gaming

I'm curious if it is possible to fool an in game timers in an old DOS game. Specifically, King's Quest 3 makes you wait 15 minutes at one point. I don't know how that timing system works or how time works in DOS. I'm wondering if there's a way to set it to just before daylight savings time and then have the clock tick forward an hour during the wait to fool the clock. I don't know whether or not that makes sense with how DOS kept time or how DOS based games adjusted their own timers.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm curious because it is a major delay in world record attempts. I am not capable of playing the game at world record speeds, but I find it interesting. The techniques they use must be achievable on period hardware, though they typically play on emulators. I'm wondering if there is a way that speed runners could skip some of that delay (which seems unaffected by speeding up the clock cycle, though other aspects of the game are).

Comment: The question seems a little too broad-scoped. Are you asking about King’s Quest specifically, or whether it's possible to intercept timekeeping interfaces in general? If the latter, there'd be a lot to write about.

Comment: As an aside, why not play King’s Quest in ScummVM instead?

Comment: DOSBox and other emulators typically have an option to change speed, because modern CPUs are too fast for those games

Comment: It depends on which TSR you clobber.  You could clobber the timer TSR and speed it up or slow it down.  It would play havoc with the system clock.

Comment: @cup Of course only if the game uses BIOS timer or a DOS function. It already gets hard if they hook it themself, and it turns impossible if they use some other mean to mark what time is.

Comment: Given DOS is not really a protected memory OS, it may be easier just to find out where the code is doing this waiting and modify it after load (or on disk if exes aren't checksummed?). I once did a similar thing to one of the early Borland (I think) dev products because it used a signed comparison to ensure you had enough memory, meaning >512K gave negative and failed. Changed it to unsigned and it worked fine.

Comment: Given how rabid some old-timers are about experiencing retro as it was, maybe you should consider putting up with the delay :-) Otherwise, it's not really King's Quest 3.

Comment: It's easy to do with the right tools, which include an emulator with support for seeing which memory locations get changed. That way you can identify the loop, identify the counter, and even automate the change of the memory location when the game hits that spot. I have not seen this kind of emulator support for DOS, though.

Comment: It seems they don't skip the 14 minutes when speedrunning KQIII "Sadly, the least interesting thing about this speedrun is that there is no known way to skip the boat ride on the pirate ship. It takes 14 minutes to sail to Daventry, and all you can do is sit there and enjoy the view." https://www.reddit.com/r/kingsquest/comments/5tq2hl/comment/ddo5ez8/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: using a debugger to hack it, I don't think it can easily be done with this game. This is a virtual machine language. You have to understand the interpreter and change the bytecode to hack it. This can be done directly, but this is really trickier and limited. Anyway, you're not supposed to cheat if you want to break a record...

Comment: The game must be reverse-engineered to know how it counts time. Only then, a DOS solution can be found to this problem, but it might need modifying the game interpreter, or game scripts, rather than speeding up timer. ScummVM already re-implements an interpreter for Sierra games so you can modify that interpreter. Or game scripts. However modifying interpreter or game scripts means it is just hacked to complete it in less time, which gives an unfair advatage for making records compared to the people that run unmodified game.

Comment: DST switchover usually needs to be done manually on DOS systems, as there are no tools or mechanisms which handle this task. So this is not usable for you.

Comment: If it's for the purposes of speedrunning, then as I understand it, any technique that involves installing a TSR or modifying game files would be considered cheating anyway, even in a TAS regime; unless you somehow find a way to achieve ACE from within the game itself. Even loading a corrupt save file would be borderline.

Comment: Are you aiming to become the Billy Mitchell of Kings Quest 3? Because I'm pretty certain *any* fiddling with the game is going to invalidate your record.

Answer (score 12):

many old games uses PIT (IIRC [i8253 programmable interrupt timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8253) chip) for timing without touching its settings. So its easily possible to chage its frequency from original 18.2 Hz to anything up to `~1192755.2 Hz` fooling DOS time too (will be much faster).

I used this a lot back in the 286 days for games like Tunneler had made a simple command line utility where you specify how much faster the clock should run and you use it prior to execute your game.

I found the old (heh 20 years) TASM source for it (its simple *.com file) called **QUICK.COM**:

```
    .386P
    IDEAL
    MODEL TINY

    DATASEG
    hdr db 'SPEKTRA software & hardware Time quicker ver 2.0',13
        db '    Made in XX XXXXX 21.12.1998 by Spektre.',13
        db 'usage: quick.com n    ... n number <18,65535>',13
        db '       n < 19  ... normal clock speed 18.2 Hz',13
        db '       n > 19  ... increased clock speed n Hz',13
    msg0    db 'No parameter found,normal clock selected.',13
    msg1    db 'Parameter found,time clock selected to      ',0
        db ' Hz',13

    CODESEG
    STARTUPCODE
    jmp main
                    ;print txt
print:  mov ah,13           ;SI-adr data,DI-adr scrn
    push di             ;save pozition on the screen
prnl0:  mov al,[ds:si]
    cmp al,ah
    jz prnr0
    or al,al
    jz prnr1
    mov [es:di],al
prnr0:  inc di
    inc di
    inc si
    cmp al,ah
    jnz prnl0
    pop di
    add di,160          ;next line
    ret
prnr1:  pop ax              ;end without ENTER 
    inc di
    inc di
    inc si
    ret
                    ;text to number
tton:   mov si,130
    sub bx,bx
    sub ah,ah
ttonl0: mov al,[ds:si]
    inc si
    sub al,48
    cmp al,9
    ja ttonr0
    mov dx,bx
    mov cx,9
ttonl1: add bx,dx
    loop ttonl1
    add bx,ax
    jmp ttonl0
ttonr0: mov ax,bx
    ret 
                    ;number to text
ntot:   mov bx,10           ;print AX number on DI pozition
    push di
ntotl0: sub dx,dx
    div bx
    add dl,48
    mov [es:di],dl
    sub dl,48
    dec di
    dec di
    or ax,ax
    jnz ntotl0
    pop di
    inc di
    inc di
    ret

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                    ;Time quicker (PIT frequency)
main:   mov ax,3
    int 16
    mov ax,0B800h
    mov es,ax

    mov di,160
    lea si,[hdr];
    call print
    call print
    add di,160
    call print
    call print
    call print

    mov bx,129
    mov al,[ds:bx]
    cmp al,13
    jz noparam

param:  call tton
    cmp ax,19
    jb pitrst
    push ax
    
    mov dx,12h          ;set PIT freq.
    mov bx,ax
    mov ax,34ddh
    div bx
    mov bx,ax
    mov al,34h
    out 43h,al
    mov ax,bx
    out 40h,al
    xchg al,ah
    out 40h,al

    add di,160
    lea si,[msg1]
    call print
    pop ax
    call ntot
    call print
    jmp ende

noparam:add di,160
    lea si,[msg0]
    call print

pitrst: mov al,34h          ;reset PIT freg.
    out 43h,al
    sub ax,ax
    out 40h,al
    out 40h,al

ende:   EXITCODE
    END
```

But its simple as just doing several `out` instructions to configure the PIT ...

If you want to speed up the time only for a specific moment you could make an TSR with hooking keyboard ISR and if specific key combination is hit activate or deactivate the speed ... This way you can workaround also games that configure PIT with their own settings (unless they hook the keyboard without running original ISR in such case use different interrupt like mouse or whatever)...

Here asm code of one of mine ancient DOS games:

- [What is the best way to move an object on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29579522/2521214)

Inspect the `int09` ISR how it is hooked up and how it works. And here ancient TASM template for TSR programs (also *.com file):

```
    intnum  equ 5

    .386P
    IDEAL
    MODEL TINY

    CODESEG
    STARTUPCODE
    
    jmp main
ints:                   ;zaciatok int
    cli
    push ds
    pusha

    mov ah,09h          ;rezident
    push cs
    pop ds
    lea dx,[txt]
    int 21h

    popa
    pop ds
    sti
intov:  jmp far 0000:0000

    id  dw 10           ;ID string (detection):lenght,string
        db 'SPEKTRA S.& H. slower v 1.0'
    txt db 'No printer found.',13,10,'$'
inte:                   ;koniec int

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    msg0    db 'Program has been succesfully installed.',13,10,'$'
    msg1    db 'Program has been succesfully uninstalled.',13,10,'$'

main:   mov al,intnum       ;test if TSR is in memory
    mov ah,35h
    int 21h
    mov di,bx
    add di,id+2-ints
    mov si,offset id+2
    mov cx,[word ptr id]
    rep cmpsb

    jz unin
    mov [word ptr intov+1],bx
    mov [word ptr intov+3],es
    mov al,intnum
    mov ah,25h
    lea dx,[ints]
    int 21h
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,[msg0]
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset inte+16
    int 27h
unin:   push ds
    mov dx,[word ptr es:intov+1]
    mov ax,[word ptr es:intov+3]
    mov ds,ax
    mov al,intnum
    mov ah,25h
    int 21h
    pop ds
    mov ah,49h
    int 21h
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,[msg1]
    int 21h
    ret 

    end
```

**P.S.** here is my `VC.EXT` extention entry for Volkov Commander association to compile in single hit with keyboard):

```
asm:@c:\language\compil\tasm\tasm !.! /ic:\language\source\tasm\inc
    @c:\language\compil\tasm\tlink !.obj /t /x
    @del !.obj
```

You can extract the compilation and linking switches from it in case you want to compile the above code... You need TASM and TLINK for that ...(IIRC TLINK can be found in bin folder of any ancient Borland Turbo C or Turbo Pascal)

The `/ic:\language\source\tasm\inc` switch is just my include folder but the code above does not use any lib anyway... the `!.!` means your source code filename with extention and `!.obj` is the same but with changed extention to obj ...